# Get Host of linked container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following setup:

```
services:
  web: &web
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - .env.web
    links:
      - google_service

  google_service:
    command: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
```

When I run `docker-compose run --publish 3000:3000 web` then I can access `lvh.me:3001` in my browser.

But when in the container `web` I try to access this url I get `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Failed to open TCP connection to test.lvh.me:3001 (Connection refused - connect(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3001)):`

**How can I access port 3001 from container google_service in the container web?** Thanks

Comment: Is lvh.me publicly resolved? Have you tried accessing `127.0.0.1:3001` from inside the container?

Comment: from the web container hit google_service:3001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Suggested by Creek, the best way here to call google service container from web container is by addressing `google_service:3001`.

In networks created via docker compose, the containers know each other by the service names, no matter whether they are linked or not. By default, they are aware about each other.

In case you want to make it accessible via host, use the IP or DNS name of the host machine OR use network mode as host "https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode" in docker compose.
While using host network mode, `localhost` will be the host machine & not the container itself.